# Which one is better name?

Tags: naming

`boolean roomIsOccupied()` and `boolean isRoomOccupied()`;  which one is better?

When I use that metod like `this.roomIsOccupied()` or `this.isRoomOccupied()`, I think both of them don't make sense, because the subject of that sentence is `this`.

Comment: I'd always go for IsRoomOccupied as it makes more logical sense....to me anyway.

Comment: programming language constructs can never fully satisfy the natural language syntax.

Comment: To my knowledge, a common coding convention is to have method names start with a verb. So `isRoomOccupied` would be preferred. Don't think of code as sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "this" is the room, use "IsOccupied()" only.

If not, I'd personally use IsRoomOccupied() because I'm used to my boolean methods starting with "Is".

Answer (score 0):

Think of it inside an `if` statement:

```
if(this.roomIsOccupied()) do_something;
if(this.isRoomOccupied()) do_something;
```

I personally find the first is better readable, but you have the last word on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think "is" reads much better.  But another reason to do this is most modern IDE's, say Eclipse in Java, if you write a boolean variable and it auto-generates the methods for you, the "getter" method signature will always be like the following.

```
private boolean happy;

boolean isHappy() { return happy }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the version starting with "is", because when you have several methods it becomes easier searching through auto completion. The same happens for methods starting with "get" or "set".